# AgGrid: add/remove rows, in Grid already having grouping/sorting/filtering applied

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

To be able to add/remove rows, in a grid which has already applied grouping/sorting/filtering, without reapplying the grouping/sorting/filtering on this row add/remove. It is that user can work on a group, updating some new values/adding new record which may still not belong to same group of grouping is reapplied, but we do not want to reapply grouping as user input will get scattered in grid, and hard to review for user.

- What we tried with ("ag-grid": "^10.0.0",     "ag-grid-enterprise": "^10.0.0",     "ag-grid-react": "^10.0.0",)
- Add a new row on some event/ btn click, in an already rendered grid with some data on startup, using the below(Skipping the refresh):

  `Let newItems = [];
     let newItem=  {
          id: 'SomethingNewId'+Math.random(),
          qty: 300,
          owner:"Deepak Kumar SHarma",
          isUpdated: true
      };
      newItems.push(newItem); this.gridOptions.api.insertItemsAtIndex(4, newItems, true); // Saying do not refresh the grid`
- After, above step, I see by iterating that a rowNode has been added, but row was not visible in grid. Then tried to refresh this newly added row only, so that it is visible in grid, expecting it to be without reapply this filter/sorting/filtering:

  `let nodes = [];
  this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode( (node, index) => {
  if (node.data!==null && node.data!==undefined && node.data.isUpdated===true) {
        nodes.push(node);
     }
  });
  this. gridOptions.api.refreshRows(nodes);`
- But still do not see the newly added row in grid.
- If I just change the sorting/filtering/grouping manually again to some new setting, I see the new row in grid.